# JWT Refresh token using Sails JS

Tags: javascript, authentication, sails.js, token, jwt

I have read a lot of posts but nothing really helped.

I am using a simple auth approach: user logs in, backend checks if its a valid user and gives back an access token using JWT. Now I want to implement a refresh token. How would that be? What should be the content of the refresh token? When I sign a new access token, what should I do to also sign a refresh token and send both of them? When I get an expired access token, how do I verify the refresh token in order to send two new tokens?

Im using Sails JS in the backend, so it would be perfect to have an example with that

Comment: Are you using passport.js? Seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt?

Comment: not using passport, but i will check it anyway, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my implementation was to create another different jwtSignature, with a different secret, and that would be my refresh token on the backend. I know it's not too fancy, but it does the work for now.